# Return all columns between dates without a specific value from another column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I wrote the following SQL query and I want to return all of the values for a date range without having to specify another columns value. Right now, I'm just commenting out 2 lines when I run the query. The value I don't want to enter every time is InstrumentID. Given the following query, how would it be best to do that? I'm running it against a ms sql server 2012 which I only have read access to, so I can't use a udf or stored proc.

```
Use MyDB
DECLARE @First VARCHAR(15), @Second VARCHAR(15),
@DateLow datetime, @DateHigh datetime, 
@InstrumentID Varchar(15)
SET @First = '<InstrumentID>'
SET @Second = '</InstrumentID>'
SET @DateLow = '2016-06-02'
SET @DateHigh = '2016-06-03'
SET @InstrumentID = 'Enter InstrumentID Here'
select * from
(
    SELECT out_interface_id, msg_id , 
    SUBSTRING(xml_msg, CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) + LEN(@First), 
         CHARINDEX(@Second, xml_msg) - 
         CHARINDEX(@First, xml_msg) - 
         LEN(@First)) as InstrumentID,
    msg_type, xml_msg, CAST(xml_msg AS XML) as [Quick_XML], 
    date_received,status, last_modified, environment,
    transaction_closed_date
    from mytable
    where msg_type in ('ABC','XYZ') 
    and date_received >= @DateLow
    and date_received < @DateHigh
) x
where x.InstrumentID = @InstrumentID
order by date_received desc
```

Comment: What do you mean you don't want to enter the value? It is part of the where clause. As posted this doesn't make a lot of sense. Perhaps if you shared what you are actually trying to do we can help.

Comment: If you don't want to always specify @InstrumentID then you can set it as null at the top and modify the where statement to read
`where (@InstrumentID is null or x.InstrumentID = @InstrumentID)`

Comment: @Chris Thanks! that was what I was looking for.

Comment: @Chris How would I change it to utilize an `IN` query instead of equal?

Comment: @MattWilliamson to use an IN the parameter InstrumentID would have to be a comma seperated list, then you would have to use a function to create a temporary table based off the comma seperated values so you can search through them in your IN - another alterantive is to use dynamic SQL - example https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from comments as it answers the question - If you don't want to always specify @InstrumentID then you can set it as null at the top and modify the where statement to read where `(@InstrumentID is null or x.InstrumentID = @InstrumentID)`